# Node.js PUT or POST request to Rails 3 Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I'm trying to make a PUT and/or POST request from Node.js to my Rails 3 server. I am passing my parameters in the body but they are not getting turned into the params hash in the Rails controller. My code is as follows:

```
http = require('http');
request = require('request');
qs = require('qs');

data = qs.stringify({name: 'Aaron', points: 10});
request_opts = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/users/update',
  method: 'PUT',
  body: data
}

request(request_opts, function() { console.log(arguments) });
```

I put a debugger in my Rails controller and params is nil but `response.body.read` returns the string I have in `data`.

How can I make a PUT / POST request from Node.js where the parameters are compatible with Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `querystring` module will serialize your data as a parameter encoded form.  By default rails expects a JSON serialized entity. You should use `JSON.stringify` instead of `qs.stringify` to serialize the your user into the request body.  Alternatively, you can explicitly specify a content-type header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to tell rails the type of the body you are sending.

Comment: You may also need to set a content-type header.  If you set this to application/x-www-form-urlencoded as per the linked question in Ben Simpson's comment, you might be able to leave the code otherwise as-is: this will depend on whether rails does content negotiation properly, though.

Comment: It was the missing content-type in the header :/

Comment: Nice, so rails does do content negotiation. I've updated answer to reflect what the options are more concisely for others with the same problem.